# Schema for the csv file

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have one text file having one column,
I have another csv files which is having data.
I need to print the schema from text file and merge this with csv file.
Is this automatically possible without using 'StructType' or using 'Case Class',like it just reads the text file,copy the whole column and transpose and paste it as 1st row for that CSV file.

**Text file**

```
Column Header
Name
Age
Roll Number
Section
```

**CSV File**

```
Fred 25 123 A
Eyaz 26 456 B
```

**O/P**

```
Name  Age  Roll_Number Section
Fred  25     123          A
Eyaz  26     456          B
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks for the time!

Comment: Hello there ! Have you a least tried something ?

Comment: Yes,i wrote in the question.but other than creating schema manually using structtype,i need that text file to be read and merge as the 1st row in csv file which is having the data in figures.

Comment: Add an example please

Comment: Text file   
   
Column header   
name   
Age   
Roll number   
Section   
   
csv file   
   
aman 25 123 a
Eyaz 27 456 b
   
   
o/p   
name Age Roll number Section
aman 25 123                a
Eyaz 27 456           b

Comment: Can you please add information editing your question an not in comment. https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

val dd= y.collect()
  val schema=StructType( dd.map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName,StringType,nullable=true)))
  println(schema)